# Show to registered user which webforms they have already submitted

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-webform

I would like to set up a views block visible to registered user listing all drupal webforms (almost 10) available on my site as a "to do list". 
When user submit webform it shoud be marked as "submitted/done" on the list. Anyone can help me?

[this is what i'd like as result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KFjy.png)

Comment: Did you try anything yet? I see that when creating a view (drupal 8 at least) under view settings for "Show" you have option "Webform submission".

Comment: I'm still trying. I use drupal 7 and i'm only able to view the list of submitted webform but i need to know which ones are still unsubmitted :(

Comment: Can you filter them by current user?

Comment: Yes Sir! I can filter submitter forms by "current user"...but i NEED to show a list of all forms NOT submitted already by "current user"... sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Well, if you are going to do it from views admin interface filters are the way. You can negate filter option. Try something on your own and post screenshot here if you don't succeed.